# Error bars in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts, errorbar

I am trying to add error bars to my highstock chart. Example of series are:

[ {name: 'Serie 1', id: 'id1',  'type': 'line', data:   [[283996800000, 285.49], [286675200000, 285.45], [289094400000, 286.31]]},
{name: 'Serie 1 error', linkedTo: 'id1',  'type': 'errorbar', data: [[283996800000, 285.1, 285.9], [286675200000, 285.4, 285.9], [289094400000, 286.0, 286.5]]} ]

The chart is initialised as  chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({ ...})

I can plot lines but once I add errorbar I get:
Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
I also tried a error_bar highchart plugin but got the same error.

Does it mean highstock does not support errorbars? I really need highstock as I also plot flags. Has anyone used highstock with errorbars?

thank you,
Iren

Comment: Have you added highcharts-more module? Highstock seems to does not have any problems with error bars  http://jsfiddle.net/0odvfhwz/

Comment: I did not realise I had to add highcharts-more module. The error is gone. Thanks for your help!